# problem with a discrete logarithm/cyclic groups example... can anyone clarify this concept for me?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

I was watching this really short video about the discrete logarithm example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SL7J8hPKEWY
and at 0:38 they show all the possible values that you can get if $p = 17$ and $g = 3$.
At 1:00 they state that the solution is equally likely to be any integer between 1 and 17.

My questios are;

- What about $0$? From what I learned about cyclic groups, $17 \bmod 17$ is just $0$. I suppose they meant a number between $0$ and $16$ then, but... why isn't the $3^x = 0 \bmod 17$ shown in the video then?
- If $3$ is really a primitive root of 17, a.k.a, a generator, that value of $x$ should exist, right? Or am I missing something?
- If $p = 17$, shouldn't the order of the group be equal to $17$ too? They are missing a value of $x$ then.
- If I'm right, what is the value of $x$ in $3^x = 0 \bmod 17$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group you are looking at is the *multiplicative* group modulo $17$ which the powers of $3$ generate.
As a set, for general $n$ this does not include $0$ and is usually written as
$$
(\mathbb{Z}_n^\ast,\cdot)
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_n^\ast \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$
for any positive integer $n\geq 2.$

If $n=p$ is a prime then this set is actually all of $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ Otherwise, it is just the set of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that is relatively prime to $n.$ If $n=p$ a prime, then the group is also *cyclic* meaning a single element $g$ can generate all its members as powers $g^i\pmod p.$

For your example $p=17,$ and $g=3.$

**Edit:** If $n$ is nonprime, say $n=pq$ where $p\neq q$ are primes then there are
$n/p$ elements in $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ that are divisible by $p.$ There are
$n/q$ elements in $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ that are divisible by $q$. Since zero is divisible by both we get
$$
n\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)
$$
elements that are relatively prime to $n$ which is the size of the multiplicative group.

For general $n$ we have  $\varphi(n)$ elements in the group, where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is *Euler’s totient function.*

Comment: Thank you very much! however I'm a little confused even after I searched about multiplicative groups, in this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n  they state they start from 0 to n-1. I thought that the additive or multiplicative notation changed only the internal binary operation without changing any property of the group itself... so an additive cyclic group goes from 0 to n, and a multiplicative cyclic group goes from 1 to n-1? Is this correct? So sorry for my confusion, I started this topic only two days ago

Comment: Shouldn't the order of the group be equal to 17 in both cases? Is it n-1 in multiplicative cyclic groups then?

Comment: @AndreaFarneti The article starts by saying "the integers coprime (relatively prime) to n from the set {0, 1, ..., n-1}". That means you have to filter the set and only keep the coprime integers.

Comment: @AndreaFarneti: …and 0 is never coprime to anything. Honestly, the lead paragraph of that Wikipedia article is a bit confusingly phrased. I can see why they do it that way — it's rather natural to start with the $n$-element [ring of integers modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), drop the additive part and the elements with no multiplicative inverse, and study what remains as a multiplicative group. But if you're *not* starting that way, listing 0 as a potential element even though it can never be coprime to $n$ is kind of confusing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thank you very much! Now its pretty clear to me... or at least to a some degree just to know what we are talking about haha